# Where to download Tanach text in digital format

Tags: tanach, product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, text

I want to download Tanach, or at least Chumash, in a word  type format. I want to be able copy and paste etc...
Any help would be much appreciated.
Yasher Kokachem.

Edit: Mechon Mamre texts are encoded in Win-1255.
Answers with UFT-8 formats are desired for Linux users to view and search the files from a terminal.

Comment: What is word type format? Do you mean Word-type (i.e. Microsoft Word-type) format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mechon Mamre's free offline resources](http://www.mechon-mamre.org) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Problem (for me) is those files are encoded in "charset=Windows-1255" not UTF-8, so for example I cannot view or search in a Linux terminal. UFT-8 encoding would be good.

Answer (score 2):

Wikitext is also good. [http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/עמוד_ראשי](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99)

Comment: Where exactly to download the text? I couldn't find. Also their "download PDF/other formats" function (along the left menu panel) is still in development and hasn't worked for me in recent past.

Comment: AFAIK Hebrew Wikisource's Tanakh text is MAM (מקרא על פי המסורה) so this answer is really just the same as the answer that recommends MAM.

Answer (score 2):

If an Excel file would meet your needs with every pasuk in Tanach appearing as a separate row then an excellent resource is a [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mkQyj6by1AtBUabpbaxaZq9Z2X3pX8ZpwG91ZCSOEYs/edit#gid=920165745) from מקרא על פי המסורה: The **Mikra al Pi HaMasora** project at WikiText/WikiSource.

I'm pretty sure it is UTF-8 compatible.  It can be downloaded to XLSX and CSV among other formats from the File / Download selection from the Google docs menu.

Caveat is that sometimes comments are encoded within the pasuk text, but it shouldn't hinder your ability to search for things.

Comment: What's the url at wikisource?

Comment: The wikisource project page for that is here: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/משתמש:Dovi/מקרא_על_פי_המסורה/מידע_על_מהדורה_זו

The link I submitted within the answer is available at the 2nd to last bullet point on the page with the following caption: הבסיס הטכני לפרויקט השלם בגליון נתונים

Comment: I have converted (and do ongoing conversions) of the MAM Google Spreadsheet into various other formats. I make these conversions available in various public GitHub repositories of mine, notably the following: https://github.com/bdenckla/MAM-parsed, https://github.com/bdenckla/MAM-XML, https://github.com/bdenckla/MAM-OSIS, https://github.com/bdenckla/MAM-for-Sefaria.